# CSS viewport width

Tags: css, width, viewport

Okay, so at this moment I am busy learning responsive CSS. It might be simple for you, but I don't understand how to archieve this:

I am playing with making a 'grid'. I have set all the classes to percentages in width and height, so that should not be the problem. However, when I resize the viewport (window), it's not dynamically growing or shrinking.

See: [here](http://responsive.favoritefm.com)

Currently using the following html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<a href="" title="FavoriteFM" class="top-logo-container"></a>
</div>
<div id="presenter">
<a href="" title="FavoriteFM" class="presenter-one"></a>
<a href="" title="FavoriteFM" class="presenter-two"></a>
<a href="" title="FavoriteFM" class="presenter-three"></a>
<a href="" title="FavoriteFM" class="presenter-four"></a>
<a href="" title="FavoriteFM" class="presenter-five"></a>

</div>

<div id="main">


</div>
```

Using the following CSS:

```
<style>

/* Theme  */
html {
margin-top: 0px !important;
}

/* DO NOT EDIT OR MONKEYS WILL BITE YOU */
.frame_holder {
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
bottom: 50px;
/* left: 50px; */
right: 150px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.my_frame {
width: 149%;
height: 108%;
/* border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; */
}

body {
    background-color: #f0ede9;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}


.clearfix {
clear: both;
}

p {
font-family: Roboto;
padding: 1px;
}



#body.layout-1 {
background: #f0ede9 url(../images/border.gif) 640px top repeat-y scroll;
background-color: #f0ede9;
background-image: url(../images/border.gif), url(../images/border-2.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y;
background-position: 640px top, 0px top;
}

a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #bababa;
font-family: Roboto;
}

#wrapper {
width: 965px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background: #2a2727;
margin-top: 20px;
color: #fff;
}

.top-logo-container {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://favoritefm.com/wp-content/themes/FavClear/img/logo.png) 5% 50% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100px;
}



#main {
margin-left: 2px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#presenter {
margin-top: 40px;
width: 100%;
height: 40%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.presenter-one {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  }



    .presenter-two {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 266px 300px;
  }

    .presenter-three {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 266px 310px;
  }

      .presenter-four {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 52%;
  width: 25%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 266px 300px;
  }

      .presenter-five {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 52%;
  width: 25%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 266px 300px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    body {
        width: 50%;
    }

    #main {
    width: 50%
    }


@media screen and (max-width: 365px) {
    body {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #wrapper {
    width: 100%
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
width: 100%;
background: #2a2727;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 100px;
}

.top-logo-container {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://favoritefm.com/wp-content/themes/FavClear/img/logo.png) 5% 50% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 120px;
}

#main {
margin-left: 2px;
}

#presenter {
margin-top: 40px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.presenter-one {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}


.presenter-two {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-three {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-four {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.presenter-five {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50%!important;
  width: 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(http://eastsbeach.com.au/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetWidth2000-Kiama-Events-Easts-Beach-PB.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%
}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve missed closing your `@media screen and (max-width: 965px)` and setting your `#wrapper` to `width: 100%;` in this breakpoint. Then it will be responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    body {
        width: 50%;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #main {
        width: 50%
    }
}
```

Additionally:
I don’t think it makes any sense to set the width of `body` and `#main` to 50 % here.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/ymq8ssw2/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but now it's not responsive anymore.

Comment: As far as I can see in your code this breakpoint gets ignored because there is missing the `}`. When this breakpoint gets active you have to set the `#wrapper` to 100 % in order to get a responsive design. I tried it on your site, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/ymq8ssw2/

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working. It's responsive at 365px now, but it doesn't adjust the width to the viewport. It's not doing the mediaquery between 366 px and 964px. It just goes to the main CSS.

See http://responsive.favoritefm.com. It's responsive, but doesn't adjust. See my code, by viewing source, because I can't post code on here.

Comment: I can’t see any problem. The site is fully responsive… in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I fixed it myself. I indeed had something wrong with closing.

Comment: I already mentioned that in my answer. As it is working properly it would be great to get my answer mentioned as correct.